# Avoid changes on FK table Django Models 1.11

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, foreign-keys

This is the way that I modeled my shopping cart.
I have a Product table, a "temporary" cart which is deleted after the order is complete. And my CompleteOrders list, which contains the data of each order of the user.
The thing is that when I modify the price or the name of my product, it changes on CompleteOrders list too. Is there a way to avoid this?

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    price = models.IntegerField()

class Cart(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)

class CompleteOrders(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
```

My approach was to store in CompleteOrder the info of the product instead of using the FK but I didn't see that very optimal.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Foreign key refers to another table and it will always show current data. You cannot avoid this. There is no other way than storing product data at the time order is completed.

I usually use JSON data type to store such information.